# jQuery detect scroll on unscrollable element

Tags: javascript, scroll, detect

I want to be able to detect `$.scroll();` on unscrollable elements. Example of such element might be something with `overflow:hidden;` but specificly it's absolute div, width 100% height and width.
I want to bind events on scroll on this div.

```
<div id="js_bgElem" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;"></div>

<script>
    $('#js_bgElem').on('scroll', function(){
        alert('Scrolled!);
    });
</script>
```

Obvious problem with this is, it doesn't work. I thought about binding only `mousewheel` and even keyboard keys, but that would not detect every possible scroll event. Such as mobile scroll down, or if anyone has rebinded or uses some sort of different scrolling.

I thought of making an extra overlay element, which would be invisible.

```
<div id="js_anchor" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed; z-index: 1; overflow: auto;">
    <div style="height: 300%"></div> <!-- Simple stretch -->
</div>

<script>
    $('#js_anchor').on('scroll', function(){
         // detect which way is scrolling
         // $(this).scrollTop(50%) so it can be scrolled infinitely
    });
</script>
```

Which theoreticly would work, but, it cannot be clicked through. Once `pointer-events: none;` is added, `scroll` is not detected anymore.

So, anyone could give me a hand with this? Thanks.